# Why is d3 pack layout crashing unexpectedly?

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, circle-pack

My code is [here](http://bl.ocks.org/tomkelly000/6214228) on bl.ocks.org:

[image]

Change the value of the select tag to limit the number of circles.  If you don't play with it much it appears to work, but particular instances (for example select 10 for TE then select 247) crash every time.  If you check the console, you'll see that the line in question is `nodes = pack.nodes(data);`.  I see two possibilites: either this is a bug with d3's pack layout, or my data is getting messed up.  Can you tell if either of these is the case, and if so, what the particular problem is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There’s a bug in your code causing child nodes to be duplicated. Since children are duplicated, there’s an infinite loop in the pack layout.

I discovered this by setting a breakpoint in the debugger and then pausing the code after letting it get stuck for a little bit. Sure enough, it was stuck in a for loop where the node’s `_pack_next` node was itself, causing an infinite loop. And it was easy to see duplicates in the children; for example, `e.filter(function(d) { return d.name === "Jermichael Finley"; })` returned two nodes, rather than one.

Comment: Thank you for that.  I've now found the bug.  I'm storing a copy of the array of players for each position so that you can add players back, but I was making the copies before calling ```pack.nodes``` on my data, which puts them in order by points projected, while they were originally sorted by some arbitrary ranking which closely resembled points projected but was tweaked slightly by ESPN's analysts for other factors.  Only when the ranking differed from the projection would players get duplicated when added back, so it happened only occasionally